# SBCL error: "No debug variables for current frame: using EVAL instead of EVAL-IN-FRAME."

Tags: terminal, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I am new to Lisp, using SBCL 1.2.11 from the terminal.

Could any one help me figure out where I should start looking to get rid of the above error? I think it is causing me the following error:

```
(setf x (list 'a 'b 'c)) 
; No debug variables for current frame: using EVAL instead of EVAL-IN-FRAME.
; (SETF X (LIST 'A 'B 'C)) ; ==> ; (SETQ X (LIST 'A 'B 'C)) 
; ; caught WARNING: ; undefined variable: X ; ; compilation unit finished 
; Undefined variable: ; X ; caught 1 WARNING condition (A B C)
```

I should not be seeing the comments, is that right?
Thank you so much!

Comment: One thing to remember: variables are not defined by SETF. SETF sets an existing variable. Define variables by LET, DEFVAR, DEFPARAMETER, by arglists in DEFUN / DEFMETHOD / FLET /LABELS... and so on.

Comment: To clarify the above comment, you should try one of the following: `(defvar x)` before your `SETF` (if you had it at the top level. Note that this is a poor name for a global variable); `(let ((x (list 'a 'b 'c))) ... do things with x ...)`, or `(defun foo (x) ... do things with x ...)` and then call `FOO`.

Answer (score 0):

[I've added this answer as there seem to be no others and in the hope that it may help.]

There are two problems here:

- you're doing something which is not legal Common Lisp (however commonly it is done);
- SBCL is warning about this in a slightly uninformative way.

There's an important bit of terminology which is common in Lisp but I think less common in other languages.  That terminology is **binding**: a binding is, loosely, an association between a name of some kind and a value.  Associated with a binding are a **scope** -- *where* it is visible -- and an **extent**, *when* it is visible.  (I am not going to talk about scope and extent because it's a big subject and this answer is already too long.)  Almost all programming languages have these three notions but they often call them different things in confusing ways.

The thing often called a variable is a name which is associated with a value: it is, in fact, a binding.  And of course the term 'binding' originates from 'variable binding'.  But not all bindings are variables -- the term is now more general and more precise (although I'm not giving anything like a precise definition here).

There are two families of constructs which deal with bindings:

- constructs which establish bindings;
- constructs which modify bindings.

*These two things are different in CL.*  In common with many programming languages there are special constructs which create bindings, and other constructs which modify (mutate) them.  Constructs which modify bindings *require the bindings to exist* so they can be modified.

### Constructs which establish bindings

In CL These are things like `let`: `(let ((x 1) y) ...)` establishes local bindings for `x` and `y` visible in its lexical scope (usually).  `defvar` and friends establish global bindings.  `defun` and friends establish global bindings in a different namespace (the function namespace, as opposed to the variable namespace) in CL, and `flet` / `labels` establish local function bindings.  There are other constructs, and in particular the set of constructs is effectively user-extensible in the usual Lisp way.

### Constructs which modify bindings

The traditional construct to modify a variable binding is `setq`: `setf` is a macro which allows you to modify bindings (and other things it calls 'places' such as elements of arrays) in a more general, and user-extensible way.  So `(setf x 2)` modifies the binding of `x`.

### The mistake

The mistake you are making is that *you can't just say `(setf a ...)`* unless there is an existing binding of `a`.  This code is illegal CL:

```
(defun foo ()
  (setf a 1)
  ...)
```

Instead you need to establish a binding for `a`:

```
(defun foo ()
  (let ((a ...))
    ...
    (setf a 1)
    ...))
```

Well, *the same thing is true at the top-level*: you can't just say:

```
> (setf x (list 'a 'b 'c))
```

because *you're trying to modify a binding of `x` which does not exist.

And this is what SBCL is telling you, in a rather uninformative (I think) way: it's telling you that there is no existing binding of `x`.

### Solutions and nonsolutions

Unfortunately CL doesn't really offer a very good solution to this problem.  One way to 'solve' it is to do this:

```
> (defvar x ...)
[...]
> (setf x (list 'a 'b 'c))
```

But this is an undesirable solution: `(defvar x ...)` turns `x` into a globally special variable -- a variable which is dynamically scoped.  This changes the semantics of any binding of x, for instance in a later function, in ways which can be unexpected.  This is undesirable.  If you want to do it, *at least* make sure your special variables follow the `*star*` convention so it's obvious which they are.

CL, out-of-the-box doesn't offer what you might want, which is 'top-level lexical variables' -- variable bindings you can declare at the top-level which *don't* do this unfortunate globally-special thing.  However Lisp is so flexible that you can actually add this to it if you want.

But still this is kind of a clunky solution: the whole point of having a conversational language is that you don't need to spend your life painfully declaring everything when you talk to the implementation: you want just to be able to say `(setf x 1)` and have that work.

And in many implementations it does work: the top-level interactive environment lets you just say that, and just does the right thing, while when you, for instance, compile a file, you will get a compile-time warning and a run-time error (possibly warning) if you do the same thing.  However this relaxed behaviour in the interactive environment is quite clearly outside the standard.

SBCL doesn't do that because, I think, it doesn't really have a top-level interactive interpreter but rather compiles everything.  So you get these warnings.  An SBCL person might want to correct me, but I think it is reasonably safe to ignore them when you're typing at the system (but *not* when you are compiling files) and treat SBCL like other implementations.

---

### A way not to fix the problem

One way that might seem sensible to fix this problem is just not to have special constructs to create bindings: a binding is created by the first assignment.  This is what Python does, for instance.  Superficially this seems like a clever trick: there's less typing and fuss.

But what is the scope of these implicitly-created bindings meant to be? (Python says 'the whole function, including bits of it which get run before the first assignment', which is, well, interesting.)  And, worse, how do you distinguish between something which is an assignment to a variable defined in an outer scope and the identical construct which is creating a binding in an inner scope: well you do that with a special 'global' construct ... which doesn't really work: Python now has a 'nonlocal' construct *as well*.  And how do you tell whether a variable is bound or not at compile time (or even, really, at run-time) to give good warnings?

The trick which seemed like a good idea actually makes things more complicated in many cases: it's reasonable for a quick-and-dirty scripting language, but less reasonable for a large-scale-systems language, I think.